# Case Assignment Rule not working from Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, case, assignment-rules

Has anyone faced the below issue with Assignment rules?

We run the case assignment rules from the trigger when certain conditions are met. It works perfectly fine.

But in the below scenario it doesn't work
Case Update > Custom Object Update > Case Update

So it's not working when the Case is updated through automation.

Any Idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Process Builder, Flows, or Workflow Rules to perform updates, the Assignment Rule won't run a second time, as noted in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). If you use a trigger to perform related updates, note that even after triggers run before assignment rules, so the earlier, original assignment rule ends up "winning" in that scenario. If you use triggers to update related records, make sure you're using [DMLOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader) with the `assignmentRuleHeader` set correctly.